# Difference in generated SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

The following c# code:

```
Func<Customer, bool> predicate1 = s => s.Name == "Roger";
dbContext.Customers.Where(predicate1);
```

generates this sql query:

```sql
select col1,col2 from customers
```

Note in the sql query above, no `where` clause.

However, in this c# code:

```
dbContext.Customers.Where(s => s.Name == "Roger");
```

it generates:

```sql
select col1,col2 from customers where name = 'Rogers'
```

Why is the difference? And is there a way to pass a predicate like above and still generate sql query with a `where` clause?

Comment: First example won't generate any SQL, because you used Func instead of Expression. Func can't be parsed, and that filter will work on server side after all Customers are loaded

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that in the first case you're calling [`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with a delegate (`Func<Customer, bool>`). The LINQ provider itself doesn't see that at all - `Enumerable.Where` will just iterate over the whole of the `dbContext.Customers` table, and apply the predicate in-process.

In the second case you're calling `Queryable.Where` with an [expression tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx). The LINQ provider can analyze this "code as data" and translate it into SQL.

This will do what you want:

```
Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> predicate1 = s => s.Name == "Roger";
dbContext.Customers.Where(predicate1);
```

Comment: Proposed answer is what I am looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the difference?

In first case you are loading all data from database and then in-memory filtering with [`Enumerable.Where(Func<T, bool> predicate)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) occurs.

In second case you are calling [`Queryable.Where(Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is converted to SQL and executed on server side (lambda expression gets converted implicitly to [`Expression<Func<T,bool>>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

> And is there a way to pass a predicate like above and still generate
>   sql query with a where clause?

Yes, you should pass expression instead of delegate:

```
Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> predicate = s => s.Name == "Roger";
dbContext.Customers.Where(predicate);
```

Just remember - Linq to Entities cannot translate plain C# method into SQL (and delegate is a simple method, just anonymous). Linq to Entities requires expression tree, which it can analyze and build SQL query based on data in tree.

Comment: Correct. How do you execute on the server side by submitting Func<Customer, bool> predicate1 = s => s.Name == "Roger"?

Comment: @Jay you should submit expression, simple delegate cannot be executed on server side